# Correct scaling argument in proof of Kolmogorov criterion for rough paths?

Tags: stochastic-processes, proof-explanation, stochastic-analysis, rough-path-theory

Regarding Theorem 3.1 of "A Course on Rough Paths" by Friz and Hairer below:
[image: Theorem 3.1 from Friz & Hairer]
The proof states that one may assume WLOG that $T = 1$. Is this due to scaling, i.e., we prove the case for $[0,1]$, then the theorem holds for the scaled process $[0,1] \ni t \mapsto X(t\cdot T)$, which is equivalent to the process $[0,T] \ni t \mapsto X(t)$?

Comment: Could you share with other users some details on the theorem (possibly a reference)? Your question is fine but, for example, I didn't ever know that there was a theorem named after A. N. Kolmogorov **and** A. G. Chentsov